# How to detect file changed by myself in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible in Intellij to mark edited file tabs with a star (*) so that I can see which files I have changed.

Comment: It's not exactly a solution, but intellij will mark your tab in a special color if your project and its files are versioned (for example git versioned).

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't use version control

Comment: Use version control. It is much more convenient to have files autosaved than having to do it manually all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Intellij automatically saves your edits every few seconds, and every time it looses focus. So, most of the time your files are not in a changed state, so no icon is needed. However, under `Settings`, `IDE Settings`, `Editor`, `Editor Tabs`, there is an option to `Mark modified tabs with asterisk`, which will enable the feature you want.

[image]

Comment: "So, most of the time your files are not in a changed state, so no icon is needed."

This is only true if you keep the default settings that cause any program of significant size to recompile and lose all static and spring context (not good).  In any case, even if it were true, the harm would be that they see a star for a few seconds.  This is actually just bad engineering.

Comment: I've been using Intellij since it was released, and I've never witnessed the problem you're describing. Perhaps you'd like to raise a question about it and we'll see if we can help you out? I'm not sure what you're calling bad engineering, but if it's intellij then you're simply wrong -- autosave is a common feature in a lot of software and whether you like it or not it couldn't be classed as bad engineering unless it didn't work.

Comment: I see that I was too subtle.

If you have a large program that has spring loading or important static member variables then these will get into a bad state when you compile.  Since you want to run a complete run without crashing, it is better for large projects to turn autosave off or increase the timeout to a more reasonable level, like 15 minutes.

However, when you change the timeout, then if you have no warning that you lose your work when your session crashes.

The bad engineering is to turn asterisks off by default.  This misses Bayes Law implications.

Comment: 3-4 seconds * cost of seeing an asterisk vs cost of losing an hour's work.  Even with a very low frequency of losing your work the asterisk off choice makes no sense as a default.  By the way, I used Intellij in 2006 and it was by far the best thing on the market.  If it weren't for lack of grails support and downward compatibility of licenses, I would probably try to downgrade my current 12 to what was out back then.